# What should we have to pass to method to complete it

Tags: java

What should I need to pass to complete this method. The error is :

> The method fireSelect(String, String[], String[]) in the type DBConnection is not applicable for the arguments (String).

This is the method :

```
public static ResultSet fireSelect(String query, String[] types,
        String[] values) {
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = getInstance().prepareStatement(query);
        if (types != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
                if (types[i].equals("int"))
                    ps.setInt((i + 1), Integer.parseInt(values[i]));
                else if (types[i].equals("string"))
                    ps.setString((i + 1), values[i]);
                else if (types[i].equals("double"))
                    ps.setDouble((i + 1), Double.parseDouble(values[i]));
            }
        }
        return ps.executeQuery();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        try {
            connection = null;
            if (cnt < 2) {
                connection = getInstance();
                cnt++;
                fireSelect(query, types, values);
            } else {
                cnt = 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception ee) {
            System.out.println("Exception :" + ee);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and this is I have use to pass during cal this method

```
ResultSet rs = DBConnection.fireSelect(
                                    "select dealer_id,car_servicing,car_servicing,cost,features "
                                            + " from dealer_car,carservicing where "
                                            + "dealer_car.car_servicing=carservicing.car_servicing and dealer_id="
                                            + dealerId);
```

Comment: If you read the error, you are passing one String but the `fireSelect` expect also two String array after that. In Java, parameter are mandatory, there is no default value like some other langage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing **String[] types** and **String[] values**, you could pass it as **null** (in your case), should be better if you call it like follow:

```
String sql = "select dealer_id,car_servicing,car_servicing,cost,features from 
dealer_car,carservicing where dealer_car.car_servicing=carservicing.car_servicing
and dealer_id=:dealer_id";
String[] types = new String[]{"int"}; //or maybe string?
String[] vals = new String[]{dealerId};
ResultSet rs = DBConnection.fireSelect(sql, types, vals);
```

Answer (score 2):

As your SQL doesn't expect any paramaters, you can simply do

```
ResultSet rs = DBConnection.fireSelect(sql, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

It expects 3 arguments, and you provided only one.
Just call like,

```
ResultSet rs = DBConnection.fireSelect("Select Query", null, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass all 3 argumens to the function fireSelect()

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL does'nt expect a paramter, it is build up by concatenation, what is not good. `fireSelect` seems to be e helper to use a prepared statement and you are avoiding this.

```
fireSelect("select * from ... where id=?", new String[]{"int"}, new String[]{"42"});
```

even this

```
fireSelect((String)null,(String[])null,(String[])null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `fireSelect` method is expecting 3 arguments:

You can use something like:

```
ResultSet rs = DBConnection.fireSelect(
                  "select dealer_id,car_servicing,car_servicing,cost,features "
                    + " from dealer_car,carservicing where "
                    + " dealer_car.car_servicing=carservicing.car_servicing and dealer_id="
                    + dealerId,
                    new String[]{"int"},
                    new String[]{dealerId});
```